# How do I prevent a leading newline in Vim when using :r!date and other shell commands?

Tags: linux, command-line, vim, shell, date

Most of the time when I'm inserting a date, I'm trying to do it in the middle of a line. By default, it looks like the `:r!` flavor of insertion always puts the result on a new line. This makes some sense to me since most shell commands output a newline before showing a command result, and this is certainly preferable in a terminal. In the case of shelling out from Vim for a tiny command like `date +%x`, this is not my preferred behavior. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In insert mode, you can use <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> to insert a expression at the current cursor position.

You could use e.g. the `system()` function, unfortunately this only solves half of the problem, since the output of `system()` will always have at least the final linebreak added to it, so it will break the line after the input. For a solution to how to avoid those final linebreaks in the `system()` case, have a look at this [answer at vi.stackexchange of mine](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17710/71).

(so you could e.g. use <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>systemlist('date')[0]<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

---

An alternative way for inserting the date at the current cursor position would be to use <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>strftime('%c')<kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> is using the *expression register* to insert content. You can find out more with the `:help i_ctrl-r` command, or [view the documentation on appspot](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R_%3D).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is not so much
that shell commands typically *end* with a newline,
but that `read` is a line-oriented command
(i.e., an [ex](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ex.1p.html) command). 
It was present in the original version of `ed`,
in the 1970s, before `:r!command` existed,
and the common use case was to read a bunch of lines
(e.g., a C function or a paragraph of text)
from one file into another. 
Most users would have wanted to insert them
as new, separate lines most of the time.

You can check / demonstrate this by doing `:r!printf Tuesday`. 
Even though the `printf Tuesday` command doesn’t write a newline
(since you didn’t specify `\n`),
you will get `Tuesday` on a line all by itself.

Perhaps the simplest workaround is to do
<kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> (to break the current line),
<kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd> to move back up a line,
then do your `:r!command`,
and then <kbd>J</kbd> to `Join` the lines back together. 
If this is something you do very often,
it might be beneficial to map a macro for it.

Disclosure: I know `vi` reasonably well,
but there’s lots of stuff in `vim` that I haven’t learned. 
There might be an easier way to do this in `vim`.